# How can I get Fragment from View?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I added some `Fragment` into a `TableLayout` and I want to manage them from my container `Activity`, so I used this:

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
```

but `getChildAt(int)` returns a `View` and a `View` could NOT cast to `Fragment`

Comment: How do you add the fragment? Through XML <fragment> tags or using a FragmentManager in Java?

Comment: I added them by using FragmentManager

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`Fragments` can be very confusing at times, especially for beginners. To understand your problem, you must learn what is a `Fragment` and how they are used.

To start with, a `View` is something that has an existence on the screen. Examples include: `TextView`, `EditText`, `Button`, etc. They are placed inside "layouts" written in Xml or Java/Kotlin. These layouts are shown using an `Activity`.

Now, a `Fragment` is not a `View`. It does not have any existence on the screen at all. Instead, it's a class that simply *manages* a layout — kinda similar to an `Activity`. If you need the View returned by your Fragment's `onCreateView()`, you can directly use `findViewById()` within your `Activity`.

If you need a reference to your Fragment, there are two possible ways of doing this:

1. If you added the Fragment using java/kotlin like this:

```java
getFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.fragment_container_viewgroup, myFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG)
  .commit();
```

You can use:

```java
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

2. If you added the Fragment inside an XML layout like this:

```xml
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
  android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You can use this:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
```

Basically, each Activity has a `FragmentManager` class that maintains all the active `Fragments`, and there are two ways of finding them: Using a unique TAG that you pass while showing a fragment, or passing the container view-ID where the fragment was added.

Comment: This answer is awesome. I added the fragment inside XML layout so I had no idea how to use them properly.

Comment: Depending on your context, you may need to call `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 37):

For people looking how to actually get a reference to the Fragment object from a View there is now a method in `FragmentManager` called `findFragment(View)` ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findFragment(android.view.View)))

```
//in Java 
FragmentManager.findFragment(view)

//in Kotlin there is an extension function
view.findFragment()
```

Be careful - it will throw an IllegalStateException if the view was not added via a fragments `onCreateView`.

Comment: I came across a problem with ImageViews from inside RecyclerView's rows loading images from network and not being added to a fragment at the time of their resource being ready. How to check if a view is aded to a fragment before calling this extension method so that we do not have to try-catch the IllegalStateException of `findFragment()`?

Comment: If the fragment contains the RecyclerView I would assume that this is not the correct method to access it, since the cells will never be added to the fragment inside `onCreateView`. I assume the simplest way to handle your use case would be to pass an interface to your ViewHolders that knows how to access whatever it is you need outside of the RecyclerView and working with that inside a specific cell.

Comment: The note about being careful is **wrong**: it is _not_ required to add the `View` via `onCreateView` for this to work. However, it _is_ required for a `View` to be attached to the `Fragment` view tree. You can successfully find the closest parent `Fragment` for any _attached_ `View`. The exception throws when a `View` is _detached_ or attached to an `Activity` (i.e. not in a `Fragment`).
The `RecyclerView` issue can be addressed by adding an `OnAttachStateChangeListener` to the `itemView` of our `ViewHolder` or by overriding `onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder)` in our `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Comment: @WesAlvaro Can you provide more context to your correction? The linked documentation states that ```This is automatically populated for the View returned by onCreateView and its children.``` In what other ways can a view be associated with the fragment so that the method would not throw an exception? Simply adding it to the view tree of the Fragment does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: I was reviewing code where the author was under the misconception that programmatically added views or any views added dynamically (e.g. by `RecyclerView`) would return nothing here. This is not the case. Yes, _some `View`_ must be returned from `onCreateView` but _any_ `View` that descends from this `Fragment` "base" `View` will return the same `Fragment`. This is because the underlying code just walks up the view tree. The only requirement is that the `View` be attached in a `Fragment`'s view tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get a fragment like this. You will have to add fragment with a tag and retrieve it by that tag.

to add a fragment do following:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, "tagTofindFragment");
```

to get fragment:

```
fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tagTofindFragment");
```

Here `tagTofindFragment` is that tag that should be unique among your fragments.